# Can an H-4 visa holder travel to the US via Canada without a visa?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, canada, transit-visas

Can an Indian national with a valid H-4 dependent visa, and travelling for the first time to Minneapolis, Minnesota transit via Frankfurt, Germany and Toronto, Canada?

The person is the spouse of an H-1B visa holder and the  itinerary is to help another person travelling with an infant.

It looks like eTA (electronic travel authorization) is needed to transit via Canada.

Because it is the maiden trip to the US, would there be a problem with these transits?

Also, does US Immigration even care about the reason for the transit via Canada instead of choosing a direct flight to Chicago?

Comment: What is an H-1B dependent visa? Do you mean an H-4 visa?

Comment: I mean spouse of H1b visa holder. I don't know what type of visa it is.

Comment: Okay.  It doesn't change the answer, actually, so maybe I shouldn't have asked.  I'm writing an answer now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that it is the initial trip to the United States does not change anything.

An Indian citizen generally needs an [airport transit visa](http://www.germany-visa.org/airport-transit-visa/) for transit in Germany.  However, holding a visa for certain other countries, including the US, exempts the traveler from this requirement.  A transit visa is therefore not needed in Frankfurt.

An Indian citizen generally needs a transit visa for transit in Canada.  The only exemption from this requirement is for US *permanent residents,* not for holders of other US visas.  Therefore, [a *transit visa* is required](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas-result.asp?country=IN&result=1&message=0&standard=1&q2=no&q3=).  I don't know where you got the idea that eTA would suffice, but that is incorrect.  An eTA is not sufficient in this case.

> Also during the entry in US, Do the immigration even bother about the reason for the transit via Canada instead of choosing direct flight to Chicago ?

They may ask about the reason, but any answer will do, whether it was a less expensive ticket or a more convenient schedule.

Comment: Thanks. I did not read the link properly before so understood eTA for only transit. So even for transit visa, it requires all sorts of formalities including biometrics! phew.

Comment: @ulab: eTA is only for people who are *visa-exempt* (like people of certain nationalities or US permanent residents). You are not visa-exempt.